# How to restrict Youtube player fullscreen still within the window, I don't want to have real fullscreen

Tags: youtube, window, awesome-wm

I have the awesome config like this below:

```
  { rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
  properties = { floating = false },
  callback = awful.titlebar.hide },
```

I don't want to have my Youtube fullscreen really playing fullscreen, but instead it is playing within the window size. If I want to have fullscreen, I could do with Win+F shortcut.

With the config above it doesn't work. Whenever I click fullscreen, it is really playing fullscreen.

I am used to be an Ion3 user and in Ion3 it just works. I am wondering whether it is possible for Awesome to do like that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on the `src` attribute of your `iframe` by adding `fs=0` parameter

```
<iframe w src="//www.youtube.com/embed/video_id?fs=0></iframe>
```

**[Parameters doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en)**

Comment: No I am talking about using awesome wm, it is not about using browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but found this while asking a similar question just now. Not sure it helps you much since I think you were trying to do the same thing I am (make it a permanent feature by adding something to rc.lua), but if you click YouTube's fullscreen button or have VLC fullscreen itself or whatever and THEN Super+F you will get the effect you want. It will defullscreen into its previous window size but the client still thinks it is in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
client.connect_signal("property::fullscreen", function(c) if c.instance == "plugin-container" then c.fullscreen = false end end)
```